In Hebrews 12-23-24, are the "angelic myriads", "congregation of the firstborn", and "righteous spirits made perfect" all descriptions of the saints?
Hebrews 12:22-24

Instead, you have come to Mount Zion, to the city of the living God,
the heavenly Jerusalem. You have come to myriads of angels in joyful
assembly, to the congregation of the firstborn, enrolled in heaven.
You have come to God the Judge of all, to the spirits of the righteous
made perfect, to Jesus the mediator of a new covenant, and to the
sprinkled blood that speaks a better word than the blood of Abel.

At Mount Zion, are the "myriads of angels", the "congregation of the firstborn", and the "spirits of the righteous made perfect" all descriptions of the same thing, specifically the transformed elect saints of God which are the adopted sons of God?
All the descriptions seem to refer to the same thing, namely the assembled sons of God in the New Jerusalem.
Does Hebrews 13:2 teach that God's elect have become angels in disguise?
Do the angels ascending and descending on Jacob's Ladder in Genesis 28:12 represent the holy elect replacing Satan and his demons?
I would appreciate any answers.

It's not appropriate on this site to ask "Your thoughts?", as that is simply asking for opinions. All questions should be asked in a way that can be answered objectively, regardless of one's personal beliefs or thoughts.

"All the descriptions seem to refer to the same thing" — Not to me they don't. The obvious literal meaning is: angels, living Christians, and dead Christians, and in the present (when it was written). The question needs to include support for why anyone would interpret it otherwise.

In the book of Enoch one can read about the dichotomy of clean and unclean angels (sons of god and/or resurrected εγρήγοροι) and righteous and sinful souls that live in heaven or kept in some pit somewhere on or under earth respectively.
This seems to be a description of the same phenomenon.
Thus the angels, sons of god, souls of sons of man and congregation of Jesus are not the same thing.

+1 and in light of this, the answer to the OP's question is "no."
